# How to use strset() in linux using c language

Tags: c, linux, string, string-function

I can’t use strset function in C. I'm using **Linux**, and I already imported string.h but it still does not work.  I think Windows and Linux have different keywords, but I can’t find a fix online; they’re all using Windows.

This is my code:

```
   char hey[100];
   strset(hey,'\0');
```

> ERROR:: warning: implicit declaration of function `strset; did you
>        mean`strsep`? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
>   strset(hey, '\0');
>
> ^~~~~~ strsep

Comment: What is that function supposed to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all `strset` (or rather [`_strset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strset-strset-l-wcsset-wcsset-l-mbsset-mbsset-l?view=vs-2019)) is a Windows-specific function, it doesn't exist in any other system. By reading its documentation it should be easy to implement though.

But you also have a secondary problem, because you pass an *uninitialized* array to the function, which expects a pointer to the first character of a null-terminated string. This could lead to *undefined behavior*.

The solution to both problems is to initialize the array directly instead:

```
char hey[100] = { 0 };  // Initialize all of the array to zero
```

---

If your goal is to "reset" an existing null-terminated string to all zeroes then use the [`memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) function:

```
char hey[100];

// ...
// Code that initializes hey, so it becomes a null-terminated string
// ...

memset(hey, 0, sizeof hey);  // Set all of the array to zero
```

Alternatively if you want to emulate the behavior of `_strset` specifically:

```
memset(hey, 0, strlen(hey));  // Set all of the string (but not including
                              // the null-terminator) to zero
```

Answer (score 1):

`strset` is not a standard C function. You can use the standard function `memset`. It has the following declaration

```
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

For example

```
memset( hey, '\0', sizeof( hey ) );
```